# Facebook share dialog not quite working in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm having a strange issue with the Facebook share dialog, and the documentation isn't much of a help. I'm using the `dialog:andParams:andDelegate` method to show it, and the first time, a login dialog shows up. If I enter incorrect credentials, it just closes and doesn't tell me they were incorrect. If I enter correct credentials, it just closes too, without showing the share dialog. However, the next time I call the `dialog:andParams:andDelegate:` method, it goes straight to the share dialog, and it works fine.

My question is, why is the dialog being completely dismissed when I try to log in? I'm not doing anything with the session before displaying the dialog, because it seems like it should handle that itself, right? Or do I explicitly have to handle a logged out session, so it displays the dialog correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that can be of any help but I use ShareKit to share stuff on social network (Facebook, Twitter, and some more). This API is really nice though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you're if you're logged in, if not call:

```
[facebook_ authorize:permissions_];
```

and then listen to:

```
-(void)fbDidLogin;
```

and save the auth tokens:

```
NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:facebook_.accessToken forKey:@"AccessToken"];
[prefs setObject:facebook_.expirationDate forKey:@"ExpirationDate"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

And after the successful login call the share dialog:

```
[facebook_ dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```